# How does the node object tree get in the browser

Tags: javascript, dom

I understand that javascript is synchronous.

But how does the Node object tree get constructed is it done in the browser where the browser produces an object referred to as 
    Node and all its properties 
for both the CSS engine to paint, and the javascript engine to transverse the html dom. Or The page when downloaded, is loaded into javascript engine and javascript parses it to get the Node tree ready in the global execution context? E.g

```
Function(fetched_page) -> Node tree constructor
```

Comment: That's an implementation detail and different browsers could take different approaches. It's also not a very good question for SO, see [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour): Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced.

Comment: @Quentin but no sane browser would use JS code to build the entire DOM tree

Comment: @Alnitak thats what it seems like to me, checking HTMLULISTElement in my browser console it returns function ()

Comment: In all likelihood the tree is constructed while the page is loading. It wouldn't surprise me if it would simply add elements to the tree as it loads, but I highly doubt the entire DOM is constructed with JS. The reason you are seeing that function is because it _is_ a function, just not one that the browser will likely use itself for construction.

Comment: @somethinghere does that mean the constructed tree is passed to js, because it is javascript that uses it?

Comment: It's nothing more than a guess, but I'm pretty sure that the tree gets constructed and added to. Just think that as its adding, it might just call a `Tree.add()` method or something so by the time your script happens, everything seems in sync. It seems unfeasibly slow to control the entire DOM using JS when you have native code available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the browser will use *native code* to parse the HTML page contents as it is loading.

Any scripts contained in the page is executed as its found (unless loaded with a `<script>` tag with `defer` and/or `async` attributes).  This is why you can't refer to an element defined in the `<body>` of a page from within a script found in the `<head>` unless you wait for an `"onload"` event or similar - those elements don't exist yet.

The DOM-related functions that are available within the browser's JavaScript interpreter are normally just hooks to the same native code functions used within the browser itself.

Comment: Okay, that sounds like it ... "Hooks to the native code of browser"